# how to use **distinct on()** in laravel's query builder if using Postgre?

Tags: postgresql, laravel

i want the syntax for **distinct on()** in laravel query builder.

Comment: I know this is old, but might be relevant to someone... Laravel does not have built in support for distinct on. I created a composer package to add support - packagist.org/packages/datajoe/postgresql-distinct-on

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eloquent does not have a [distinctOn](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/10863) function.

You could use a raw query

```
$query->select(
    \DB::raw("DISTINCT ON (field1, field2) *")
);
```

or install a package that adds the `distinctOn` method, such as [this one](https://packagist.org/packages/datajoe/postgresql-distinct-on).

If you're using Laravel 9 or above - [native distinct on support is available](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/v9.0.0/Query/Grammars/PostgresGrammar.php#L178), as long as you're using the Postgres driver.

```
$query->distinct(['field1', 'field2']);
```

Comment: this is not working with my already ->select()

Comment: ->select(["AssessmentAssignment.Name",
               \DB::raw('"AssessmentAssignment"."EndDate" + "AssessmentAssignment"."EndTime" AS "EndDateTime"') "])

Comment: how it can fit into myalready select

Comment: You have to include AssessmentAssignment.Name in the raw query.

Comment: no, the issue was somewhat different, i was not letting me add a raw query on the beginning, i added it with existing raw query, and it worked.

Comment: I know this is old, but might be relevent to someone... Laravel does not have built in support for distinct on. I created a composer package to add support - https://packagist.org/packages/datajoe/postgresql-distinct-on

Comment: @jacobfogg Thanks, I've added a link to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think distinct on() is in laravel , but you can try:

$query = DB::table('users')->select('name')->distinct()->get();

The distinct is applied on select "name" in this example.

Comment: this isnt working for me :(
thats why i was looking for distinct on